Where to store key for Secure Configuration Properties?
I encrypted my properties and wanted to use Secure Configuration Properties, but I don't understand where to store the key. I tried setting it in Run configuration Environment, Argumets, and also as my System environment variables, but my project would fail to run.

You need to define a configuration property to use it to configure the password. Use one of these options:

System Properties in wrapper.conf or command line:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/configuring-properties#system-properties

Command line:
mule -M-Dsecret=123456

wrapper.conf:
wrapper.java.additional.999=-Dsecret=123456


System Properties in Anypoint Studio: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/configuring-properties#setting-system-properties-in-anypoint-studio


Right-click your project in Package Explorer.
Click Run As > Run Configurations.
Pick the Arguments tab.
Add your arguments to the VM arguments field, preceding property names with -D


Properties in Runtime Manager: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/configuring-properties#setting-properties-values-in-runtime-manager


Log in to your Anypoint Platform account.
Click Runtime Manager.
Either click Deploy Application to deploy a new application, or select a running application and click Manage Application.
Select the Properties tab in the Settings section.

After you set the property with whichever method you can use it directly in the configuration:
<secure-properties:config key="${secret}" file="config.yaml" name="config">
    <secure-properties:encrypt/>
</secure-properties:config>

